# Canon EF-S 10-18mm IS STM on a Canon 1300D

Tags: lens, canon, ef-s

I am planning to buy the [*Canon EF-S 10-18mm IS STM*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_10%E2%80%9318mm_lens) for my [*Canon EOS 1300D*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_1300D) as a better alternative to snap panorama / outdoor architecture photos.

From what I've read this lens appears to be compatible with the camera, but as I am new to the DSLR business I'd like to make sure I am correct:

- Will it mount on my camera? *EF-S* should be OK, am I right?
- Will there be any undesirable cropping? I think it should match the *APS-C* sensor, so there should not be any, am I correct?

Are there any obvious drawbacks over the stock lens ([*Canon EF-S 18–55mm III*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF-S_18%E2%80%9355mm_lens)) (apart from the smaller zoom)?

Do you think there will be a noticeable improvement for panorama photography for this particular camera?

Comment: Having enough of opening cameras just to have the film exploding in your face, eh, Professor? ;-)

Comment: There is no drawback as it is not meant to replace it but to complement it.

Comment: I own the 10-18 IS STM and it's personally one of my favorite lenses, especially in its price range. It has a very smooth focus ring and (unlike some other STM lenses) it's STM motor is virtually silent. The IS works fast and reliable and if it weren't for my 24mm prime I'd almost exclusively use the 10-18mm for wide landscapes and archtitecture photography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canon EF-S range of lenses are designed specifically for the Canon APS-C range of cameras.

The Canon 1300D is an APS-C camera and therefore, the Canon EF-S 10-18mm Lens will work perfectly with this camera. What you see through the viewfinder is what you will capture with no further undesirable cropping.

If you were using this on a full frame camera such as the Canon 5D, there is a possibility that some EF-S Lenses can extend deeper into the camera and with a flange of 44mm, may extend past this distance and hit the mirror. An EF-S lens may also result in an image that will have all four corners blacked out.

The obvious drawback of the 10-18mm over the 18-55mm stock lens will be the reach.

Other noticeable drawbacks of such a lens are as follows;

•   Distortion and stretch when subject is too close

•   Prone to vignette specially if you use filters which happen to not be the thinnest available

•   can produce soft edges

On the other hand, besides achieving a greater FOV, the 10-18mm STM lens has a Stepper motor which has an advantage over the 18-55mm when it comes to video as its almost silent.

Comment: Thanks. From what I understand, the mentioned drawbacks are not specific to the lens, but are common to UWL in general. Am I correct?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore - Thats correct.

Comment: EF-S lenses *can* extend rear elements deeper into the camera body. Most of them don't, though. The EF-S 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6 IS STM is one that probably does at the widest focal length settings. But it is a gross overgeneralization to imply that all EF-S lenses do.

Comment: @MichaelClark - Yes.. An oversight. correct wording is perhaps "there is a possibility that some EF-S Lenses can extend deeper into the camera". "and with a flange of 44mm, may extend past this distance and hit the mirror"

Comment: You say drawback, I say feature.

Answer (score 2):

> EF-S should be OK, am I right?

Your camera has an EF-S mount, so it'll work with any EF-S lens, including this one.

> Will there be any undesirable cropping?

No. There won't even be any desirable cropping.

> Do you think there will be a noticeable improvement for panorama photography for this particular camera?

There will definitely be an improvement if the problem with the lens you have is that it's not wide enough. The fact that this lens has image stabilization whereas your kit lens doesn't may help. Reviews seem enthusiastic with respect to image quality. So it seems like a good choice, but if you're nervous about it you could do either of the following:

- **Visit a camera store and try it out.** If you do this, it's good form to buy the lens there. It might cost a little more than buying online, but the ability to take a look before buying and to get advice on the spot has a lot of value.
- **Rent before buying.** You can [rent this lens](https://www.lensrentals.com/rent/canon-ef-s-10-18mm-f4.5-5.6-is-stm) for a week for about $25 plus shipping, so you can try it out and see if it's what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Gear preferences are really a matter of individual aims and taste. What is for one person a 'noticeable improvement', might not at all address what you hope to improve in your panoramas.

I suspect this is why one is discouraged from asking shopping questions.

The best option is to go to a brick-and-mortar store that sells the equipment and try it out either in the showroom or by renting the equipment you are thinking about and give it a whirl 'in the field' to see if it suits your needs.
Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks. Will the lens be compatible with the camera, though?